# A way to test Spring Security's (5.6.x) secure annotations in services

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Is there a way to test Spring Security's (5.6.x) secure annotations in **services** not in controllers?

I see many solutions, however, no one works for me. I suspect the deal in the version (5.6.x).
I tried the solution from the documentation ([4.2.2.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/test-method.html)), but it didn't work for me.

My current test annotations:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SecurityTestExecutionListeners
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
class PostAuthTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private PostAuthService service;

    @Test
    @WithAnonymousUser
    void testSuperSecureMethod() {
        assertThrows(ForbiddenClassException.class, () -> service.someSuperSecureMethod());
    }
}
```

Tested class:

```
    public class PostAuthService {

    @PostAuthorize("returnObject.length() > 5")
    public String someSuperSecureMethod() {
        return "123";
    }
}
```

Service's secure annotations work fine as I run them within the app.

I prefer to avoid `SpringBootTest` annotation in service's tests as far as it seems overwhelming for here. What I try is to test `PostAuthorize` with authentication and returned object mocks.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a great section on testing in the Spring Security [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/method.html#test-method-setup).

Comment: How do you create your `Service` instance? You have to add it to your application context.

Comment: @dur, your solution works. the bean wasn't in the application context, InjectMocks creates an instance outside the application context. I've added bean to ContextConfiguration so the tests work properly now

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/method.html#test-method-setup

> @ContextConfiguration instructs the spring-test the configuration to
> use to create the ApplicationContext

as @Eleftheria Stein-Kousathana is kindly provided.

Thanks to @dur, the solution is to fix the issue that the InjectMock doesn't create a bean in the test ApplicationContext.

The solution:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { PostAuthTest.Config.class})
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
class PostAuthTest {

    @Autowired
    private PostAuthService service;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Test
    @WithAnonymousUser
    void testSuperSecureMethod() {
        assertThrows(AccessDeniedException.class, () -> service.someSuperSecureMethod());
    }


    @Configuration
    static class Config {

        // this bean will be injected into the OrderServiceTest class
        @Bean
        public PostAuthService postAuthService() {
            // set properties, etc.
            return new PostAuthService();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!